# How to check if auto-scaling is enabled for an ECS-service using AWS go SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-go

As the question above states, is there any way to determine if the autoscaling for a service is enabled. I have been looking through the AWS Go SDK documentation but been unable to ascertain how to do so.

On the web API side too, it seems they lack any direct API for doing so. Is there any workaround to determine whether the auto-scaling is enabled or not?

Answer (score 0):

Please read this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-auto-scaling.html)

By default, the ECS is only keep the desired count containers work for highly available.

If you want auto scaling, it is an additional and optional service refer to the above link. That service has a role named AWSServiceRoleForApplicationAutoScaling_ECSService in the example. You can check that role